# CSS not recognizing hover color set

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a filter search list on javascript and nested the elements of my list under 3 different categories.

- Cuenta NT
- Training On the Job
- Manual de procedimientos

The table works great while looking for any of these terms and retrieves them instantly. However, the list is intended to grow very much and I want the table to display a color similar to the one on the headings when the mouse hovers the results.

The problem is this:

Despite the background-color property was properly defined in the CSS sheet, I cannot see any color displaying while hovering the mouse on any of the results.

**CSS**

**#myUL li a.1:hover:not(.header) {background-color: #FCF3CF;}**

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
 li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
 
 for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color:#f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a.1:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #FCF3CF;
}

#myUL li a.2:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #D5F5E3;
}

#myUL li a.3:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #D6EAF8;
}

#myTable1 {
 background-color: #F9E79F;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable th.com {
 background-color: #F9E79F;
}

#myTable2 {
 background-color: #76D7C4;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable th.toj {
 background-color: #76D7C4;
}

#myTable3 {
 background-color: #85C1E9;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable3 th.doc {
 background-color: #85C1E9;
}




p.invisible {visibility:hidden;
    display:inline;
    font-size:0.5px;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<h2>Matriz de Búsqueda Global</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar" title="Teclea para localizar">


<ul id="myUL">
  
 <table id="myTable1">
 <tr><th class="com">Cuenta NT</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="1"><a href="#">Cuenta NT
   <p class="invisible">
   Cuenta NT
   </p></a></li>


   
  
 <table id="myTable2">
 <tr><th class="toj">Training on the Job</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="2"><a href="#">Training on the Job
   <p class="invisible">
   Training on the Job
   </p></a></li>



  
 <table id="myTable3">
 <tr><th class="doc">Manual de procedimientos</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="3"><a href="#">Manual de procedimientos
   <p class="invisible">
   Manual de procedimientos
   </p></a></li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is the problem. Add a complete description of what to do with your snippet (what to write), what happen, it is wrong and what you want to get there...

Comment: I'd advice against tables here. While I like the notion of this being data displayed tables are not meant for more complex datasets like this with several headings inside of them. A11y is going to have a hard time read this out. Instead try divs with the appropriate headings?

Comment: It is intended to be a small table for the Human resources department. Nothing fancy, somehing they wanted to replace an excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, class names must not begin with a numerical character, so i renamed your classes to `.x1`, `.x2`and `.x3`. Second, use this selector `#myUL li.x1 a:hover` on the first of your hover rules, and similar ones for the others as shown below.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
 li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
 
 for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color:#f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li.x1 a:hover {
  background-color: #FCF3CF;
}

#myUL li.x2 a:hover {
  background-color: #D5F5E3;
}

#myUL li.x3 a:hover {
  background-color: #D6EAF8;
}

#myTable1 {
 background-color: #F9E79F;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable th.com {
 background-color: #F9E79F;
}

#myTable2 {
 background-color: #76D7C4;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable th.toj {
 background-color: #76D7C4;
}

#myTable3 {
 background-color: #85C1E9;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable3 th.doc {
 background-color: #85C1E9;
}




p.invisible {visibility:hidden;
    display:inline;
    font-size:0.5px;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<h2>Matriz de Búsqueda Global</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar" title="Teclea para localizar">


<ul id="myUL">
  
 <table id="myTable1">
 <tr><th class="com">Cuenta NT</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="x1"><a href="#">Cuenta NT
   <p class="invisible">
   Cuenta NT
   </p></a></li>


   
  
 <table id="myTable2">
 <tr><th class="toj">Training on the Job</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="x2"><a href="#">Training on the Job
   <p class="invisible">
   Training on the Job
   </p></a></li>



  
 <table id="myTable3">
 <tr><th class="doc">Manual de procedimientos</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="x3"><a href="#">Manual de procedimientos
   <p class="invisible">
   Manual de procedimientos
   </p></a></li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advise. I knew there was something wrong with naming the classes with numbers but I couldn't tell what. U Saved my a$%$ bro,

Answer (score 1):

Do not use numbers as a name for html classes, it messes with the meaning of "classes" and your CSS too.
I changed 1,2,3 to child1, child2, child3
And i changed the their css, !important is set to assure the style applies (So it does not get overwritten).

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
 li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
 
 for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color:#f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li.child1 > a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #FCF3CF !important;
}

#myUL li.child2 > a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #D5F5E3 !important;
}

#myUL li.child3 > a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #D6EAF8 !important;
}

#myTable1 {
 background-color: #F9E79F;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable th.com {
 background-color: #F9E79F;
}

#myTable2 {
 background-color: #76D7C4;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable th.toj {
 background-color: #76D7C4;
}

#myTable3 {
 background-color: #85C1E9;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-align:left;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#myTable3 th.doc {
 background-color: #85C1E9;
}




p.invisible {visibility:hidden;
    display:inline;
    font-size:0.5px;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<h2>Matriz de Búsqueda Global</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar" title="Teclea para localizar">


<ul id="myUL">
  
 <table id="myTable1">
 <tr><th class="com">Cuenta NT</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="child1"><a href="#">Cuenta NT
   <p class="invisible">
   Cuenta NT
   </p></a></li>


   
  
 <table id="myTable2">
 <tr><th class="toj">Training on the Job</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="child2"><a href="#">Training on the Job
   <p class="invisible">
   Training on the Job
   </p></a></li>



  
 <table id="myTable3">
 <tr><th class="doc">Manual de procedimientos</th></tr>
 </table>

   <li class="child3"><a href="#">Manual de procedimientos
   <p class="invisible">
   Manual de procedimientos
   </p></a></li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Mario. Thank s a lot for your answer. I just noticed that you replied to my question first so I thought I should support you too. I'm not very experienced in stackoverflow yet. Is there a way I can contribute to the incrase of your reputation in the website? Let me know, thanks.

Comment: @T100 Do not worry, I am glad we've helped you!.